# How to change JList?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I am working on a programm with some buttons and a `JList`.
It is very simple and the only thing it can do is to show the clicks made in a `JList`.
Its a school programm, I have to make it with a `JList`.

I managed to get it working with a `JLabel` (which counts all clicks and shows it on the bottom) but not with an `JList`.

There are four buttons, and each of them has a own counter. How can I update the `JList` (the count of the specific button which is clicked) in the `JList`?

I made for each button a `int` variable which is updated in the `actionPerformed` method whenever the button is clicked.
The `JList` shows those variables, with the button names in front of it.
But it stays on `0`, how can I update the `JList`?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Task1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

public int m1 = 0;
public int m2 = 0;
public int m3 = 0;
public int m4 = 0;

JButton Menue1;
JButton Menue2;
JButton Menue3;
JButton Menue4;
JLabel unten;
JLabel text;

JList<String> Liste;



public Task1(){
    setTitle("Menüauswahl");

    // Bereits gewählte Menüs
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        add(panel, BorderLayout.EAST);

    text = new JLabel("Bereits gewählte Menüs  ");
        panel.add(text);

    String[] menues = {"Menü 1: " + m1+"x", "Menü 2: " + m2+"x", "Menü 3: " + m3+"x", "Menü 4: " + m4+"x"};
        Liste = new JList<String>(menues);
        panel.add(Liste);

    


    // Menürbar
    JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();

        JMenu Datei = new JMenu("Datei");
        menubar.add(Datei);
        setJMenuBar(menubar);


    // Gesamt Menüs
    unten = new JLabel("Menüs Insgesamt: 0", SwingConstants.CENTER);

        unten.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        add(unten, BorderLayout.SOUTH);



    // Menü-Auswahl / Buttons
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        
        panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2, 10, 10));
        add(panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            Menue1 = new JButton("Menü 1");
            Menue1.addActionListener(this);
            panel1.add(Menue1);

            Menue2 = new JButton("Menü 2");
            Menue2.addActionListener(this);
            panel1.add(Menue2);

            Menue3 = new JButton("Menü 3");
            Menue3.addActionListener(this);
            panel1.add(Menue3);

            Menue4 = new JButton("Menü 4");
            Menue4.addActionListener(this);
            panel1.add(Menue4);


    //Fenster Config
    setSize(450 , 300);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
        
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent click) {
  
    if(click.getSource()==Menue1){
        m1+=1;
        System.out.println(m1);
        unten.setText(String.format("Menüs Insgesamt: " + (m1+m2+m3+m4)));
        
    }

    if(click.getSource()==Menue2){
        m2+=1;
        System.out.println(m2);
        unten.setText(String.format("Menüs Insgesamt: " + (m1+m2+m3+m4)));
    }

    if(click.getSource()==Menue3){
        m3+=1;
        System.out.println(m3);
        unten.setText(String.format("Menüs Insgesamt: " + (m1+m2+m3+m4)));
    }

    if(click.getSource()==Menue4){
        m4+=1;
        System.out.println(m4);
        unten.setText(String.format("Menüs Insgesamt: " + (m1+m2+m3+m4)));
    }

}


public static void main(String[] args){
    new Task1();
    

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your example is school-level (not as an offence, I just don't want to rewrite it all), we'll keep it simple.

As of now you're directly imputting items in the `JList` through its constructor

```
String[] menues = {
   "Menü 1: " + m1+"x", 
   "Menü 2: " + m2+"x",
   "Menü 3: " + m3+"x",
   "Menü 4: " + m4+"x"
};

Liste = new JList<String>(menues);
```

This works for showing only, as you don't have access to a `ListModel` that is capable of updating.
Thus we need to instantiate ourself a `DefaultListModel`

```
private final DefaultListModel<String> listModel;
```

and add our initial values

```
listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
listModel.addElement("Menü 1: 0x");
listModel.addElement("Menü 2: 0x");
listModel.addElement("Menü 3: 0x");
listModel.addElement("Menü 4: 0x");
```

Now, construct the `JList` with that `DefaultListModel`

```
Liste = new JList<>(listModel);
```

We can then update the list items using our model directly in `actionPerformed`

```
if (click.getSource() == Menue1) {
   ...
   listModel.setElementAt("Menü 1: " + m1 + "x", 0); // Indexes start at 0!
}

if (click.getSource() == Menue2) {
   ...
   listModel.setElementAt("Menü 2: " + m2 + "x", 1);
}

if (click.getSource() == Menue3) {
   ...
   listModel.setElementAt("Menü 3: " + m3 + "x", 2);
}

if (click.getSource() == Menue4) {
   ...
   listModel.setElementAt("Menü 4: " + m4 + "x", 3);
}
```

Anyway, remember to [read the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html), always!

Comment: I had managed to do it myself with a youtube video, just in the moment you posted the comment ^^ 
But my code was unneccessarily wrong, I first cleared the list and added everything again on every button click.
Now I´ve done it like You showed and its working just fine and the code is smaller too. 
Thank You so so much !! :)